# How to make thicker stroke for the texts with css?

Tags: html, css

```css
.masks{ width: 200px; height: 60px; position: relative;}
       .bgMask{
           width: 200px; height: 60px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; right: 0; transition:1s;}
        .masks:hover .bgMask{width:0;}
       .bgMask span{ 
           display: block; width:200px; height: 60px; font-size: 54px;
           position: absolute; right: 0; color:teal;
        }
        .outlineMask{
            width:0px; height: 60px; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;
            left: 0; transition: 1s;
        }
        .outlineMask span{ 
           display: block; width:200px; height: 60px; font-size: 54px;
           position: absolute; left: 0; color:teal;
           text-shadow: 0 0 1px hotpink, 0 0 1px hotpink, 0 0 1px hotpink, 0 0 1px hotpink, 0 0 1px hotpink; color:#fff;
        }
        .masks:hover .outlineMask{width: 200px;}

        .masks span{
            font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
            letter-spacing: 0.1em;
        }
```

```html
<div class="masks">
        <div class="bgMask"><span>STORE</span></div>
        <div class="outlineMask"><span>STORE</span></div>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to create the text mask effect for the menu with css, and I tried to make a text to have stroke using text-shadow; however with my knowledge the only way to make the stroke more clear and not blurry it to layer them like `text-shadow: 0 0 1px hotpink, 0 0 1px hotpink, 0 0 1px hotpink, 0 0 1px hotpink, 0 0 1px hotpink; color:#fff;` which doesn't look smart. Will there be another way to put clear, strong strokes around the texts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, currently the only available working option for a "**Text Stroke**" is by using and layering text shadow prop.

Altho, there is an experimental one called "**-webkit-text-stroke**", but i dont recommend it for any production projects.

you can read more about that expermintal webkit here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke